# how to catch the exit event of process in docker

Tags: docker

I create a process with nodejs on docker container, but I don't catch the exit event of the process, the docker version is 1.0.1, but the same code is okay on the version 0.91 of docker.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var exec = spawn('docker', 'run busybox /etc/bin/bash each hello world');

exec.on('error', function(err){
   console.log(err);
});

exec.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
});

exec.on('exit', function(err){
    console.log('exit')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the use of `spawn`. The second parameter should be an array [according to the nodejs docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

In a quick test, your code launches `docker` without any arguments, at least on node v0.10.28.